# React Native useState causes data loss when mapping for the first time. how do i solve this?

Tags: typescript, react-native

```
const initialData = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: `${accountList?.brideName} ${accountList?.brideSurname}`,
      type: 'Gelin',
      selected: false,
      tlText: accountList?.brideAccount?.accountTl,
      euroText: accountList?.brideAccount?.accountEuro,
      dollarText: accountList?.brideAccount?.accountUsd,
      accountHolderType: 'BRIDE'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: `${accountList?.groomName} ${accountList?.groomSurname}`,
      type: 'Damat',
      selected: false,
      tlText: accountList?.groomAccount?.accountTl,
      euroText: accountList?.groomAccount?.accountEuro,
      dollarText: accountList?.groomAccount?.accountUsd,
      accountHolderType: 'GROOM'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Ortak Hesap',
      type: 'Gelin & Damat ',
      selected: false,
      tlText: accountList?.commonAccount?.accountTl,
      euroText: accountList?.commonAccount?.accountEuro,
      dollarText: accountList?.commonAccount?.accountUsd,
      accountHolderType: 'COMMON'
    },
  ]

const [Data1, setData1] = useState<Data[]>(initialData)
```

I have a state in which I hold data like this and I map this state as you can see below.

```
<ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
            {Data.map((item, index) => {
              console.log('data5 ', accountList?.brideAccount?.accountTl);
              return (
                <View>
                  <PressableOpacity
                    onPress={() => {
                      setSelectedById(item.id);
                      console.log('data6 ', accountList?.brideAccount?.accountTl);
                    }}>
                    <View
                      style={{
                        paddingVertical: responsiveHeight(13),
                        paddingHorizontal: responsiveWidth(24),
                        borderBottomWidth: 1,
                        borderBottomColor: '#F3F3F3',
                        justifyContent: 'center',
                      }}>
                      <Text
                        style={{
                          lineHeight: 22,
                          fontFamily: Fonts.semiBoldRaleway,
                          fontSize: 14,
                          letterSpacing: 0.2,
                          color: '#000',
                        }}>
                        {item.name}
                      </Text>
                      <Text
                        style={{
                          lineHeight: 16,
                          fontFamily: Fonts.regularPetrona,
                          fontSize: 10,
                          letterSpacing: 0.3,
                          color: '#EA80AA',
                        }}>
                        {item.type}
                      </Text>
                      <Icon
                        style={{
                          position: 'absolute',
                          right: responsiveWidth(24),
                        }}
                        name={
                          item.selected
                            ? 'chevron-down : feather'
                            : 'chevron-right : feather'
                        }
                        size={20}
                        color="#061937"
                      />
                    </View>
                  </PressableOpacity>
                  {item?.selected && (
                    <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: responsiveWidth(24) }}>
                      <Text>{accountList?.brideAccount?.accountTl}</Text>
                      <CustomInput3 value={item?.name} />
                      <CustomInput3 leftImage={Images.tlBlack} value={item?.tlText} onChangeText={(value) => handleChangeTl(index, value)} />
                      <CustomInput3
                        leftImage={Images.dolarBlack}
                        value={item?.dollarText}
                        onChangeText={(value) => handleChangeDollar(index, value)}
                      />
                      <CustomInput3
                        leftImage={Images.euroBlack}
                        value={item.euroText}
                        onChangeText={(value) => handleChangeEuro(index, value)}
                      />
                      <CButton text='Kaydet' onPress={() => {
                        // console.log(item.accountHolderType)
                        onSubmit({ weddingCode: weddingC, accountTl: item.tlText, accountEuro: item.euroText, accountUsd: item.dollarText, accountHolderType: item.accountHolderType })
                      }} />
                    </View>
                  )}
                </View>
              );
            })}
```

This is actually a modal component and when I first open this modal, the data is undefined.
When I close it and open it a second time, the data appears.
What do I need to do to see the data first?

There is no problem in pulling the data, when I log the data appears first.
I think there is a problem with state. how do i solve this

Answer (score 0):

You can add useEffect to your call like this :

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (initialData.length) setData1(initialData);
    else setData1([]);
  }, [initialData.length]);
```